# Create multiple separate heatmaps from a single matrix

Tags: r, graphics, matrix, data-visualization, heatmap

I want to visualize a 42x42 matrix as 28 separate heatmaps, each heatmap being 6x6 matrix with the values plotted on the top of colours. I only need lower half of he matrix, I don't want to plot anything that has been excluded. The subsequent 6x6 matrixes shouldn't overlap, as in the example below:

```
d = as.matrix(read.table("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2505196/matrix_posthoc_tukey.dat"))
d[upper.tri(d)] <- NA
d1 <- d[1:6, 1:6]
d2 <- d[1:6, 7:12]
d3 <- d[1:6, 13:18]
d4 <- d[1:6, 18:24]
#...etc, up to d28 <- d[37:42,37:42]
```

Code I used to create a single heatmap looks like this:

```
#baseline to create a separated space for all 28 plots
par(mfrow=c(4,7), mar=c(2,2,4,1), oma=c(2,4,2,2))

#using `image` to create heatmap, with color breaks defined by specific values
#the code below create just single heatmap
image(x=1:6, y=1:6, axes = FALSE, ylab="", xlab="", d1, 
  breaks=c(min(d1,na.rm=TRUE), -5.45, -4.65, 4.65, 5.45, max(d1,na.rm=TRUE)),
  col=c("red","orange","white","orange","red"))
axis(2, 1:6, cex.axis = 0.7, las=1, tick=F)
axis(3, 1:6, cex.axis = 0.7, tick=F)
#create vertical and forizontal lines
abline(h=seq(0.5,6.5,1), v=seq(0.5,6.5,1))
#plot values from the specific matrix subset
for (i in 1:6)
   {
     for (j in 1:6)
       {
         txt <- sprintf("%0.1f", d1[i,j])
         text(i, j, txt, cex=0.7)
        }
   }
```

Three such heatmaps look like this:

[image]

That's where I'm stuck. I have to manually change `d` value every time I add another image to my single-page, multiple heatmap collection. I don't know how to create a nice loop to plot those specific subsets of matrix at the same time using the code above.

Alternative solutions with ggplot2, lattice are also welcomed, although I believe the main question here is a good loop to make this series of heatmaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite a complex plot, but it can be readily produced by the standard graphics library in R. It is more or less only a matter of keeping track of what indices goes into which panel. The way you extract the `d1` to `d28` matrices can be automated so you don't have to write out each and every line.

```
# Get the submatrices
I <- unlist(lapply(0:6, function(a) a:6))
J <- rep(0:6, 7:1)
d2 <- mapply(function(i,j) d[1:6+6*i, 1:6+6*j], I, J, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

# Setup the layout and add an outer margin for the title and axis labels
layout(matrix(c(1:28, 0, 0), 5, 6))
par(oma=c(3,3,3,1), mar=c(2,2,1,1))

# Plot all the matrices oriented the same way they appear in text
# i.e. the first (vertical) dimension is plotted along the Y-axis
for(k in 1:length(d2)){
    x <- 1:6+6*J[k]
    y <- 1:6+6*I[k]

    # Heatmap & grid
    image(x, y, t(d2[[k]][nrow(d2[[k]]):1,]), las=1, axes=FALSE,
          breaks=c(-1e10, -5.45, -4.65, 4.65, 5.45, 1e10),
          col=c("red","orange","white","orange","red"))
    xg <- apply(!is.na(d2[[k]]), 2, sum)
    yg <- rev(apply(!is.na(d2[[k]]), 1, sum))
    segments(c(x[1]-1, x)+.5, min(y)-.5,
             c(x[1]-1, x)+.5, min(y)+c(6, yg)-.5, xpd=TRUE)
    segments(min(x)-.5,         c(y[1]-1, y)+.5,
             min(x)+c(6,xg)-.5, c(y[1]-1, y)+.5, xpd=TRUE)

    # X & Y-axis values
    mtext(x, 1, .1, at=x, cex=.5)
    mtext(rev(y), 2, .2, at=y, las=1, cex=.5)

    # Values of each cell
    text(rep(x, each=6), rep(rev(y), 6),
     sub("NA", "", sprintf("%.2f", d2[[k]])), cex=.3)
}

# Add title and axis labels
title("All 28 submatrices", outer=TRUE)
mtext("Columns", outer=TRUE, 1, 1)
mtext("Rows", outer=TRUE, 2, 1)
```

The numbers in each cell may be tiny, but if you plot it to a pdf and zoom in they can be read. The `xpd` parameter of the `segments` functions supressess R from clipping the lines to the plot area (otherwise the outer lines would appear slightly thinner).

[image]

Comment: The grid in your example figure can be added with `segments`, and if you want to draw the x-axis numbers above each panel change `mtext(..., 1, ...)` to `mtext(..., 3, ...)`.

Comment: This is very promising. How can I make colour breaks in `image` the same way as I do in my code? And how would you use `segments` there - I'm bad in looped stuff...

Comment: How about that? The grid code can be a bit hard to interpret, but if look run the expressions, e.g. `min(y)+c(6, yg)-.5`, you'll see it's just a way of getting the start and end positions of each line.

Comment: This is epic mate, I will definitely give you some bounty reps for this. The only thing that doesn't work is that it won't highlight the negative values within the range defined in brakes (e.g. in the second panel it's -5.37, -5.86). Any idea why?

Comment: It does highlight the negative values, but it uses same color as for the positive ones :) That's how you wrote it so I figured you were interested in the extremes, regardless of sign. So change the first two colors to "blue" and "cyan" or something. Glad you like the plot, I produce loads of plots at work and thought yours was kinda fun.

Comment: Indeed, I'm interested in the extremes regardless of sign, but still if you double check your code here you will see that it somehow omits the negative values...

Comment: You're right! I accidentally wrote `1e-10` where it should have been `-1e10`. The code works now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18874/discussion-between-backlin-and-geek-on-acid)

Answer (score 1):

To have 6x6 sub-arrays of your original matrix you may act as follows:

```
for (i in seq(1, 42, 6))
    for (j in seq(i, 42, 6)) {
        dsub = d[i:(i+5), j:(j+5)]
        ...
    }
```

However I suggest using a better way to create heatmaps - rather than re-inventing it. Although my favorite package for making normal heatmaps - as you want with numbers inside the cells - is `pheatmap` (= pretty heatmap), but it does not support multiple small heatmaps in the same page. This is just an example of `pheatmap()` output, you may see the help of the function by running `?pheatmap` after you have installed and loaded the package.

[image]

To have multiple heatmaps in the same page you may use `ggplot2` package. Here are good manuals of [how to make ggplot2 heatmaps](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/) and also [having multiple plots on the same page.](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Multiple%20graphs%20on%20one%20page%20%28ggplot2%29/)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detailed example of how you would use the loop you suggested with my code?

Comment: If you are going to use your own code for making the heatmap, you can completely copy it inside the loop body. Then use dsub as the 6x6 matrix you want to make heatmap for (like as d1, d2  of your original code)

Comment: @GeekOnAcid What's the problem? The dsub variable should contain the 6x6 array of your desire. you may just use print(dsub) after dsub = ... command to see the result.

Comment: No, `dsub` only gives me a single sequence from the first 6 rows of the matrix `d`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a nested loop, and your d#'s will have to be an array (I'll call it subs for submatrices). Excuse my code as I do not really know R but something like this:

```
for (row in 1:7)
  {
    for (col in 1:7)
      {
        subs[((row-1)*6)+j] <- d[ ((row-1)*6) + 1) : (row*6), (((col-1)*6) + 1) : (col*6)] 
      }
  }
```

This will give you all 49 submatrices. If you only want the first 4 columns of submatrices you can range col from 1:4 in the loop.